# Android publishing two apps with same package id

Tags: android, google-play, nativescript

Inside of the Android Developer Console I would like to have 2 applications, MyAppName and MyAppName-Staging. The only differences between these two apps would be:

1. The API environment they point (prod vs. staging)
2. One would be for external Play Store release while the other (MyAppName-Staging) would be intended only for internal users in my company.

Would I be allowed to use the same package/app ID for both of these or would I need to change the package ID for each one? My assumption is I would need to change it, if thats the case can I use the same code base but just change the app ID and rebuild the apk to achieve this?

For additional context I've built this app using Nativescript. So all packaging info is handled through a `package.json` file and code signing must be done through the CLI. I just want to make sure I can't code sign myself into a situation where I can't release my build to production (the MyAppName build) Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, Google Play Store doesn't allow 2 apps having the same package name to be published. You would need to either:

1. Change your package name

or if you want to have the same package name regardless,

2. Upload your staging app (with the same package name) to the beta channel of your live app then select users to be invited to the beta.

Comment: If I went with option 2 could the application have a separate App name? As in how it displays on the phone when you use it?

Comment: absolutely, changing the display name (not the package name) can simply be done in `Android Manifest` file

Comment: Awesome this may do exactly what I need then

Answer (score 1):

The developer console has the concept of beta builds that you can distribute to list of members or open to play store. You could build with same package name but pointing at different environment and distribute through there.

Then point back to prod when you release your official build.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en